# Determining and restoring Window state in Linux

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I use xlib. I want to remember window position and restore it to that position the next time it starts. This will help the user as he won't need to move/size the window to the desired position at every start.

It works more or less Ok, except one case. When the window is maximized, I cannot find the way to determine its true (non-maximized) size and position. Perhaps someone knows how to do it?

Comment: Can you show us your code and narrow down your question a bit? Because right now what you're asking is too broad to be useful.

Comment: Remember the geometry every time it changes while not maximized. That way you know the most recent geometry before it was maximized.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly there's no way to get it from window manager similar to GetWindowPlacement() in Windows and I need to track the changes. But the window manager can set the maximization properties either before or after changing the size. Can I count on maximization properties being already set when the window size is changing as a result of maximization?

Comment: Your program shouldn't rely on the window manager much. There's no guarantee one is present, or behaves like you would expect. The window placement after un-maximization (or un-minimization, or un-shading, or...) is the window placement before maximization (minimization, shading, ...) so just remember your last "non-special" placement.

Comment: There would be no maximizations without window manager. And without window manager nobody would move the windows around as if they knew better how the program is used. How do I find out if the placement is "special" or "non-special"?

Comment: Hm you are right. You do need to ask the window manager what your state is (maximized or not). But this is minimal interaction with WM and should be kept as such. If the WM doesn't support _NET_WM_STATE  you just treat the window as never maximized. I think thee WM should first change the state itself, then update _NET_WM_STATE property, but to be absolutely sure, watch both resize events and _NET_WM_STATE property changes, and be ready for either one coming first.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't as far as I know a standard way to do this. If you read the source to Metacity for example you can see it keeps this unmaximized size in the MetaWindow object but I don't think it gets stored in a property, and I don't see a property for this in the EWMH or ICCCM specs.

It's possible that some specific window managers might store it in a nonstandard property.

When a window is maximized you could get a property change event with the maximization flag (libwnck is an old library to track this sort of thing, maybe there's a newer one I don't know). However I doubt it's defined whether the resizing happens before or after setting the flag. You could perhaps heuristically assume that a resize covering most of the screen within 1 second of setting the maximize flag was a maximize, or some similar hack.

All that said, I suspect the easiest way to get this feature is to implement it as a window manager extension or plugin, which many WMs support in some way.

There is an old spec for this (X session management protocol) unfortunately the spec is ridiculously broken, unclear and essentially impossible to implement. A core issue that was never addressed - and probably needs app cooperation to address - is how to recognize "the same" window across restarts in order to restore its size.
There are only flawed heuristics for that.

(I wrote metacity and worked on a couple session managers long ago so once I could have told you a lot more, but I've forgotten many details.)